# Type of test for control and 3 variants or treatments

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test

if I was thinking to design test for a control and 3 treatments or variants looking at a 0 dollar value for control and then 5,10 and 15 dollar amounts for completing an assignment, would a normal t-test be fine or anova?

I am a little confused as ANOVA states to compare to each other but here I just want to see which is best option in relation to my control

Thanks!

Comment: What means "looking at a 0 dollar value" here? Also, what does "completing an assignment" refer to? Does this describe your outcome?

Comment: Sorry completing an assignment means an assignment or survey a user can complete, with incentives like those dollar amounts to do so, just want to know what would be best test to use here for the a/b test

Comment: So your outcome would be the ratio $n_{agree}/n_{asked}$ of the number $n_{agree}$ of people that agree to do a survey to the number $n_{asked}$ of people that are asked to do the survey?

Comment: What do you mean by "the best test to use for the a/b test"? What's the hypothesis you want to test with this experiment?